# Rewrites in htaccess not hiding filename

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a site where I am rewriting the URL to use a file `package.php` but with the URL `http://example.com/package-type/airport/hotel-name`. It works fine when going to the pages. However, Google Webmasters Tools is reporting errors with the URLs `http://example.com/package.php?/package-type/airport/hotel-name`. Why isn't my htaccess rewrites working for Google? Here is my rewrite code in the htaccess file:

```
#Redirects hotel pages to package.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /package.php?/$1 [L]

# Removes package.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*package\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.​*?)package\.php/*(.*​) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
# Removes package.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /package\.php\?(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,NE,L]

#Redirects hotel pages to package.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /package.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This looks like it will work. But I won't be able to test it until Monday 11/23.